# Is there a way to target HTML in an Array with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, class, dom

I have an array:

```
wireholder.wires[]
```

This array holds HTML `tr` elements with `td` children in each iteration:

```
wireholder.wires[1] = 
<tr class="trClass" id="blah">
    <td class="tdClass0">
         <select class="selectClass">
             <option value="1">Option1</option>
             <option value="2">Option2</option>
             <option value="3">Option3</option>
         </select>
    </td>
    <td class="tdClass1">
         <input class="inputClass1" type="text" />
    </td>
    <td class="tdClass2">
         <input class="inputClass2" type="text" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

I want to be able to target the class names in this arrays iteration.

Something like `$(wireholder.wires[i].classNameHere)` would be exactly what i'm after.

Has anyone heard of any ways to do something like this?

---

### Solution

```
for(i=0;i<oldElement.length;i++){
    if($(node).find('.wire_selector_' + row).length){
        var oldWire = $(node).find('.wire_selector_' + row).val();
    }
    if($(node).find('.wire_length_' + row).length){
        var oldLength = $(node).find('.wire_length_' + row).val();
    }
    if($(node).find('.wire_retail_' + row).length){
        var oldPrice = $(node).find('.wire_retail_' + row).val()*100;
    }
}
```

---

### For vol7ron

```
function DomFactory() 
{
    this.buildElement = function(elementType, props) {
        var el = document.createElement(elementType);
        for (var prop in props) {
            el.setAttribute(prop,  props[prop]);
        }
        return el;
    };

    this.buildTextNode = function(nodeData) {
        var node = document.createTextNode(nodeData);
        return node;
    };
}
```

Then using DomFactory:

```
var dom_builder = new DomFactory();
        var part_stub = dom_builder.buildElement("tr", {'class': "wiring_details_" + Wireholder.wires.length + "-" + part_id + "-" + zone_id, 'id': "wiring_rows_" + Wireholder.wires.length});
        var part_td = dom_builder.buildElement("td", {'colspan': '2'});
        var wire_type = dom_builder.buildTextNode("Wire Type: ");
        var select_wire = dom_builder.buildElement("select", {'class': 'wire_selector_' + Wireholder.wires.length, 'name': 'select_wire_' + Wireholder.wires.length});
        var wireValues = ["Select wire..", "14/2", "14/4", "16/4", "16/2", "RG6", "CAT5", "RG59", "LVT", "CAT6", "HDMI", "Shielded CAT6"];
        var length_stub = dom_builder.buildElement("td", {'colspan': '2'});
        var wire_length = dom_builder.buildTextNode("Length: ");
        var wire_length_input = dom_builder.buildElement("input", {'type': "text", 'class': 'wire_length_' + Wireholder.wires.length, 'name': 'wire_length_' + Wireholder.wires.length, 'value': '1'});
        var retail_stub = dom_builder.buildElement("td", {'colspan': '2'});
        var wire_retail_price = dom_builder.buildTextNode("Retail Price: ");
        var wire_retail_input = dom_builder.buildElement("input", {'type': "text", 'class': 'wire_retail_' + Wireholder.wires.length, 'name': 'wire_retail_' + Wireholder.wires.length, 'value': '0'});
        var total_stub = dom_builder.buildElement("td", {'colspan': '2', 'class': "wire_total"});
        var add_button = dom_builder.buildElement("a", {'href': "#", 'class': "add-button", 'id': "wiring_button_" + Wireholder.wires.length});
        var add_wire = dom_builder.buildTextNode("Add Wire");
        var wire_id = dom_builder.buildElement("input", {'type': "hidden", 'id': 'wire_id_<?php echo $part->id; ?>', 'name': 'wire_id_<?php echo $part->id; ?>', 'value': '<?php echo $part->wire_id; ?>'});
        that.appendChild(part_stub);
        Wireholder.wires.push(part_stub);
```

There is more but you get the idea...

Comment: I don't think you can just store HTML in a JS variable/array element  like that.  It'll have to be a string or object of some sort.

Comment: It works if I do `wireholder.wires[i].getElementByTagName("select")[0];`?

Comment: @Myles Gray: again... how are you storing your HTML? Pretty sure you have to encapsulate it in a string.

Comment: @vol7ron - It uses a function called DOM Builder above to build the HTML as demonstrated above then is pushed to the array.

Comment: @Myles Gray: ahh, so you're using DOM objects, which is slightly different from HTML; yeah I had to look up someone using [DOM Builder](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CBgQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcodingpatterns.blogspot.com%2F2008%2F06%2Fjavascript-dom-builder.html&ei=2juGTcaIDeSQ0QGbmNHNCA&usg=AFQjCNH2FvAi4dCDBxYdjBU2KH3UT96bCQ), though I'm not sure it's exactly the same function.  Be careful on your terminology, you're using DomFactory, which is a custom function; YAHOO created something similar called DOM Builder, which the person in my link is using.

Comment: @vol7ron Thats the one, I keep forgetting the difference!

Comment: @Myles Gray: can also micro-optimize the above for loop `for (var i=0,n =oldElement.length;i<n;i++)` or if you can do a reverse-for/while loop, it's another faster implementation.

Comment: @Myles Gray: I think it's also important to note that the jQuery find() function will return an array if multiple matches are found, which is something to consider.  If your schema only has one selector/length/retail per node, then I don't think you have to worry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(wireholder.wires[1]).find(".tdClass1")
```

By wrapping it with `$()` you make it into jQuery "collection" that can be searched for specific class etc..

Comment: @mpl not really, you can pass literal HTML string to jQuery and it will make it into its own object, perfectly useable by any other (jQuery) code. :-)

Comment: Very clever. Initially it was not visible in the question how the array held a string.

Comment: @mpl it showed weird assignment of HTML into the array so it led me to the correct conclusion. :-)